# Any Windows Manager Controler libraries for Python/C/C++?

Tags: python, window-manager, c++, c

I was wondering if there are any libraries for **Python**, **C** or **C++** that help you interface with your window manager/x-windows? I am currently using `os.subprocess` and feeding it `wmctrl` bash commands and though this kind of works it feels very dirty.

I've found a couple of libraries that try to do this, but they are all from 2016 (or way older) and usually version 0.something which is kinda questionable. I am **not** looking for something like **Qtile** or a different window manager as I frankly quite enjoy the Gnome window manager, I just want to extend it slightly with some personalized scripts.

I'd prefer it if the libraries are in Python, C or C++ but if you know of some which are written in different languages I'd be happy to hear about those too :D

Comment: Good is subjective ;-) I removed it  but there is a chance people will still disagree with me... asking for lists is also not accepted.

Comment: @Rinzwind Fair, thanks for removing it. and what do you mean that asking for lists is not accepted? I'm just looking for a library doing a thing in one of three languages. How it that asking for lists of things?

Comment: Oh you are asking for "any libraries" That is asking for someone to create a list but it looks like there is only 1 so it stops there already  :D

Comment: I don't agree with your definition of any, but okay. Most certainly since I couldn't find any myself.

Comment: Oh I did not act on it ;-) Just made an observation :+

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [libwnck](https://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/).

API docs for the Python bindings are [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Wnck-3.0), you need to install the package `gir1.2-wnck-1.0` to use them.

It should be usable with C++, too, but I've never tried that.